# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS random freezes

Tags: 18.04

For sometime now I have been experiencing random freezes whilst doing random tasks. It is a low spec laptop however it happens even when just running Vscode + Firefox whilst other times when I am running multiple applications/tasks its all fine. I have attached my logs in the hope that someone could shed a bit of light in my case.

```
10:35:51 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
10:35:49 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
10:35:41 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
10:35:38 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
10:35:38 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.2: AER:    [12] Timeout               
10:35:37 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
10:35:37 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.2: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
10:35:36 kernel: snd_pci_acp3x 0000:03:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode : 1
10:35:36 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x9e501000-0x9e504fff]
10:35:36 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
10:35:36 kernel: do_IRQ: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
10:35:36 kernel: do_IRQ: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
10:35:36 kernel: do_IRQ: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
10:35:36 kernel: do_IRQ: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
```

Many thanks for your help.